# What is the background of writing the c in McLastname with the small c on the top of the line with a line under it?

Tags: writing

In a recent conversation with my mom she mentioned how as a child she would write her last name with the small c parallel to the top of the big M and a hyphen under it. (See example below, not real name of course)  My mother lived her childhood in British India. Her parents were both American citizens, but they lived in India (where her dad had grown up) so there was a heavy heavy British influence on her childhood. Was this a British way to write Mc names? Or was this standard across the English speaking word until typewriters/computers eliminated it?

[image]

Comment: This may answer your question: it seems to have been a common (though not universally used) way to write Mc names, which has become rarer since typewriters and computers made it harder https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/334927/moving-the-lower-case-c-up-above-type-in-the-last-name-mcneil

Comment: It's actually an abbreviation, like the o in the numero sign: №

Comment: Related: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/100564/what-is-the-name-for-the-kind-of-abbreviation-that-employs-an-underlined-supersc

Comment: Also my answer [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/353447/can-one-abbreviate-the-spanish-given-name-jos%C3%A9-mar%C3%ADa-to-jos%C3%A9-m%C2%AA-in-english-like/353589#353589)